# How can redirect SCIP console output to a text file with AMPL interface?

Tags: scip

I am using SCIP through the AMPL interface in Julia/JuMP, and I'd like to redirect the console output to a file. Is there an easy way to do this? With Gurobi and IPOPT, I can pass in the desired file name as an option. I didn't see something similar listed in the SCIP options.

Thanks,
Alex
(a new SCIP user)

Answer (score 1):

If JuMP doesn't give you an option to capture the stdout of the solver, then there is currently no way to do this without modifying the source.
If you can modify the source, then here is a simple patch to get the output into a file foo.txt additionally:

```
--- a/interfaces/ampl/src/cmain.c
+++ b/interfaces/ampl/src/cmain.c
@@ -43,6 +43,8 @@ SCIP_RETCODE run(

    /* setup SCIP and print version information */
    SCIP_CALL( SCIPcreate(&scip) );
+   
+   SCIPsetMessagehdlrLogfile(scip, "foo.txt");

    SCIPprintVersion(scip, NULL);
    SCIPinfoMessage(scip, NULL, "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the `AmplNLWriter` package with JuMP, which creates a .nl file and then uses the AMPL-compatible SCIP executable. It supports passing SCIP options via a scip.set file.

Is there a simple way to modify the SCIP source to accept the filename for the output file (replace _foo.txt_) as an input?

Answer (score 1):

This patch will add an option 'display/logfile' to set the name of a logfile. You don't get the very beginning of the log (SCIP version and external codes) into that file, though. If you need this, just reorder cmain.c accordingly.

```
--- a/interfaces/ampl/src/cmain.c
+++ b/interfaces/ampl/src/cmain.c
@@ -38,6 +38,7 @@ SCIP_RETCODE run(
    SCIP* scip;
    char buffer[SCIP_MAXSTRLEN];
    SCIP_Bool printstat;
+   char* logfile = NULL;

    assert(nlfile != NULL);

@@ -57,6 +58,11 @@ SCIP_RETCODE run(
       "whether to print statistics on a solve",
       NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL, NULL) );

+   SCIP_CALL( SCIPaddStringParam(scip, "display/logfile",
+      "file to additionally write log to",
+      &logfile, FALSE, "", NULL, NULL) );
+   assert(logfile != NULL);
+
    SCIPprintExternalCodes(scip, NULL);
    SCIPinfoMessage(scip, NULL, "\n");

@@ -65,6 +71,8 @@ SCIP_RETCODE run(
    {
       SCIP_CALL( SCIPreadParams(scip, setfile) );
    }
+   if( *logfile )
+      SCIPsetMessagehdlrLogfile(scip, logfile);

    SCIP_CALL( SCIPgetBoolParam(scip, "display/statistics", &printstat) );
```